# How to use the latest available XMLHttpRequest in JScript

Tags: xmlhttprequest, jscript, chakra

I use the following command to launch a JS script: `C:\Windows\System32\cscript.exe /nologo //E:{16d51579-a30b-4c8b-a276-0ff4dc41e755}` in order to use the latest Chakra engine.

In my script, the command `WScript.Echo( ScriptEngineMajorVersion() + "." + ScriptEngineMinorVersion() + "." + ScriptEngineBuildVersion());` outputs `11.0.19326`.

I know this increases performance, and I thought I'd be also able to use the latest `XMLHttpRequest` instead of the good old `Microsoft.XMLHTTP` (I need [responseURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/responseURL)) but it looks like I am not.

Is there a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is, the way you're loading the Chakra engine it's loading an invisible IE instance.  But [according to this MDN compatibility table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#Browser_compatibility) there is no version of Internet Explorer that supports `responseURL`.

#### edit: don't use JScript

Through much testing, attempting to load Edge's Chakra engine into Windows Script Host, I can land on no permutation that works.  Creating an `htmlfile` COM object and forcing compatibility using `x-ua-compatible`, attempting the same with an HTA application (both natively and again with an `htmlfile` COM object), attempting to create a `MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0` object, no Windows Script Host hack I can conceive will expose the `.responseURL` property of an XMLHttpRequest object.

Best bet would be to pick a different language.  In PowerShell you could do something like this:

```js
$req = [Net.WebRequest]::Create("https://youtu.be/")
$resp = $req.GetResponse()
$resp.ResponseURI.AbsoluteURI
```

... which would print

```js
https://www.youtube.com/?feature=youtu.be
```

And if you need the equivalent of `.responseText`, just add the following:

```js
$reader = new-object System.IO.StreamReader $resp.GetResponseStream()
$responseText = $reader.ReadToEnd()
```

If you want to parse $responseText using DOM methods...

```js
$htmlfile = new-object -COM htmlfile
$htmlfile.IHTMLDocument2_writeln($responseText)
$buttons = $htmlfile.getElementsByTagName("button")
```

You can see the [original revision of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/55998395/1) for an example of what *doesn't* work.

Comment: I have tried what you suggested, but I'm getting a `NetworkError` on `xhr.send()` (request working with `Microsoft.XMLHTTP`) and I can't retrieve more information because when I try to `catch` the Exception, it's `null` or `undefined`

Comment: @Twistingnether Shoot. Well, in my testing I'm not getting a network error (try `xhr.send('')` instead), but I'm failing a little farther down the line. Because the `htmlfile.parentWindow.XMLHttpRequest()` class passes its result object asynchronously, the `onload()` method doesn't appear to be exposed to a single-threaded JScript instance the same way `Microsoft.XMLHTTP` or `MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0` COM objects are. I'm still experimenting to see if I can find you a workaround. At the moment, the only kludge I can think of will be to use JavaScript in an HTA application instead of JScript.